# Google App Script setValue() function not holding

Tags: google-apps-script, cell, setvalue

I'm trying to make cell A of my Google Sheet mirror the value of the most recent cell to be changed, which we will call cell B. Therefore, when some cell B's value changes, so does A. However, anytime I setValue() of A to be that of B's upon B's value being edited, A briefly contains B's value and then empties out again (the value only flashes for a second).

This is my current code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var B = e.value; // a non-specific Cell B, which has just been edited

  var validation = ss.getSheetByName("Target Sheet"); // Sheet containing Cell A
  range = validation.getRange("A1"); // Cell A
  range.setValue(B);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: onEdit only triggers on user edits

Comment: Yes but this wasn't the problem - I was triggering it via cell edits

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Not sure exactly what the problem was, but this seems to have worked:

```
var range = validation.getRange('A1').clearContent();
range.setNumberFormat('@');
return range.setValue(B);
```